# android: webservice image replace with images in Local folder

Tags: android, web-services, image

I am into final stage of chat application in android.

I am facing few issues while working with images and web service.

So when i select the image and sent that image to web service i get URL from service. How can i convert that url into image that is in my local folder. I am confused how can i make this working.

I want to display the selected image in list view along with message returned from web service.

Please guide me in this issue.   Is there another option to work this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            connection.setReadTimeout(120000);
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here You need to pass the URL of the image to the function and you can set the image as setImageBitmap function.

Comment: Respected,  Thanks a lot in taking time for helping me. : I have a grid view with 30 smileys. so according to my code i am able to display image that s selected in edit text. so when i submit i get message from web service as hi [OBJ]. I need to replace that with my smiley image i sent to web service. This s my issue. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to convert url into image   `Bitmap bi=convertImage(url);`, mention your image sizes in this line

bit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,120, 120, true);

```
public Bitmap convertImage(String url)
         {

            URL aURL = null;
            try 
           {
            final String imageUrl =url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
            Log.e("Image Url",imageUrl);
            aURL = new URL(imageUrl);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(bis)); 
            if(bm==null)
            {}
            else
              bit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,120, 120, true);

            return bm;

           } 


            catch (IOException e) 
            {
               Log.e("error in bitmap",e.getMessage());
              return null;
           }


          }
```

Set returned bm(bitmap) to your ImageView `imageview.setImageBitmap(bi)`
feel free to ask doubts

Comment: Respected, First thanks a lot in taking time in helping me. Can you post me any sample code. since i need to understand the code. any sample example i can see that working, i can understand. Your code i can well understand . But any sample example would be a great help. 1 more doubt is: I have a gridview with 30 smileys. so acc to my code i am able to display image that s selected in edit text. so when i submit i get messge from webservice as hi [OBJ]. I need to replace that with my smiley image i sent to web service. This s my issue. Pls guide me friend