# replace image in local folder with URL coming from web service

Tags: android, web-services, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: webservice image replace with images in Local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564961/android-webservice-image-replace-with-images-in-local-folder)

How can I replace an image in local folder with the URL received from web service. Please provide me a sample code or a simple example.

Guide me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url="http://....";
 String FILENAME;
    InputStream input=new InputStream(url.openConnection()
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
    fileDest=new File(FILENAME);

        if ( fileDest.exists() ){
            if ( ! fileDest.delete() )
                throw new Exception (
                        "impossible to delete "+ fileDest.getName());
        }
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(bis.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I guess you can start with this.